# How can I decrease reading data latency between two EC2 servers in Singapore and Japan region?

Tags: amazon-web-services

How can I decrease reading data latency between two EC2 servers in Singapore and Japan region?

I put Python API codes in Singapore and MongoDB database in Japan region. Whenever Python API codes in Signapore try to read database, it takes 0.5 seconds to get the result. If it tries read database in same region, it only takes 0.02 seconds. Is there a way to increase speed? or I have to understand it because it is far away between two servers.

I checked [Enabling Enhanced Network](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/network-throughput-benchmark-linux-ec2/) and [Placement Groups](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/placement-groups.html), but it doesn't look like the answer in my situation.

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe replication? Have a read-only replica in Singapore, then only updates need to go all the way to Japan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a huge workload, caching results of your queries could also help.

Amazon provides fully managed caching engine for such purposes:
https://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/